# Can I save this machine?

Tags: updates

Hey All I'm low on computer skills and need some help on how and which os to replace my windows XP it's an older e machine AMD Athlon 64 processor 2.2GHz 1600MHzFSB

Comment: How much RAM? What video? Often older systems work well with Lubuntu, does your system boot from USB flash or is it older and only boots from CD/DVD? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LubuntuLinks

Comment: Does the graphics adapter support 3D acceleration? If not, Ubuntu 14.04 is not an option. Lubuntu, my personal choice for old hardware should work, though. If you can swing 2 GB of RAM, I think you'd have a better experience, though 1 MB can work.

Comment: I can answer about the ram it says 1.87 GB of ram, I'm not sure about the graphics and as for booting I used a windows XP pro disc to load but it's no longer in machine and no Flash either. Video is ATI RADEON XPRESS200 with PCI Express slot available

Answer (score 0):

The CPU is more than powerful enough. You'll want at least 1GB RAM for Ubuntu. If you have that, then Ubuntu should be a good match. If you have less, then you might want to get Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

But in either case, when you're replacing an opeating system, I recommend that you take some time to explore alternatives. My suggestion is that you try Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, Lubuntu and Xubuntu. All of them can be run from a DVD or memory stick without installing anything and all of them can do anything that Ubuntu can do, but the desktops are rather different and they have different default applications, etc.